# Android Studio Activity Layout Changing

Tags: android

I need help in changing layout of Activity in Android Studio when I click on button.

But I don't want to open new activity I want to change layout and design completely on the current activity by clicking button. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you can inflate another layout during `button` click:

```
    public class LayoutInflateDemo extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout layoutToAdd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_existed);
        layoutToAdd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.existedlayout);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                        .from(getApplicationContext());
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_toinfliate, null);
                //Add the inflated layout to your existing view 
                layoutToAdd.addView(view);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

layout to inflate Xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/mytext"
  android:text="Inflated layout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is your existing layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/existedlayout"
    >
   <Button  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Clicck to inflate view"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How to switch between layouts if I have multiple buttons on single activity ?

Comment: just inflate different layout during mulitple button click...and add them to your existing layout

Comment: I am total new to android studio. Sorry for stupid question. But inflate Xml I will create or is it already there and I will add this code ?

Comment: **layout_toinfliate**   is the id of your layout resource...which u need to show during button click---you need to create it and add the code to your file

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible by using `setContentView()` method. But you have to make sure that you didn't use any view (e.g. view by id) that is not available on current layout.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is **Fragments** and **FragmentActivity** https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html